# How to recreate "Ship to a different address" checkbox on WooCommerce checkout where you can copy all the fields data into new custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

How to recreate "Ship to a different address" checkbox on WooCommerce checkout where you can copy all the fields data into new custom fields. For Example, All the data I will input on billing details when I click a checkbox will be put into the patient details field.

[image: Screenshot 1]

---

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: For that, you can write javascript to get value from billing details and set or clear to patient details on the checkbox checked

Comment: if you want to save patient details to order you can use checkout page hooks and action here is the link.
1) https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/
2) https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-checkout-page/